# How to stop laravel users to swapping between devices

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a web app written on laravel 5.6, is already on the server (i got a private one), but often time some users are swapping , and take control from the other user like for 1 minute straight in some cases, this is a big trouble, for security reasons, they can see and even can change data for the other user.

This users are based on the Authentication documentation for laravel, here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

And based on roles, this is the code for my Middleware (users)
I have this problem quite often

```
  if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->rol == 'User') {
      return $next($request);
  }
  elseif  (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->rol == 'Admin'){
      return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
  }
  elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->rol == 'Afiliado') {
      return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
  }
  else{
      return redirect()->route('login');
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to check the endpoint that allows a user to select/change their role. There's a possibility that the 'rol' attribute is being set via a request value or the logic of saving the role is incorrectly implemented.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you considered the diff between Autentication and Autorization? Auth only checks if a user is valid (the credentials are OK!)... Autorization make sure users can only do what they are allowed to do (even if they are authenticated)... With a solution like policies you prevent users to do stuff with OTHER users data, even if they are valid users... I could give you a detailed example of what I mean, but have you at least considered this as the problem?

Comment: as @redcenter jotted , using gate and policy would do the trick . https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: Hello , I wanted to make a multiAuthentication app,  i tried use a relationship between user and role (roles has many users), then apply a middleware, one for the auth(authentication), and other for the role, which is the code in the first post.
So everytime someone makes a request to the server, i just apply the middlware @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: But the error is not that the middleware is failing, but sometimes the users JUST SWAP, some user could be on mexico, and other on usa or spain, and they will mix up for some reason, sorry but thats my trouble.
I think i still could use the Authorization, due my users are already Authenticated, but i fear the swaping will continue, although this is only my problem, its better to remakethe system. @Tithira

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question as i resolve it a while ago.
When two users send request to the server between a short time period (1 - 5 seconds). 
The second user will identify as the first one.
This is cause by the "micro-cache", as this was enabled by default on the host server.
One solution is to add this headers on every request that you don't want to store on the cache

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

But as we wanted to be disable on all request, the best solution is to contact your server landlord to disable it on the config file.